# Long running query in EF 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The following query should return about 7200 records:

```
            using (var context = new RapEntities())
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            var query = from i in context.QbTxnItems.AsNoTracking()
                        where (i.ListType == "Invoice")
                        && !context.Payments.Any(p => p.QbTxnId == i.QbTxnId && p.QbTxnId != null)
                        && !context.QbTxnIgnores.Any(ti => ti.QbTxnId == i.QbTxnId)
                        orderby i.RefNumber
                        select i;

            var items = RapEntities.GetList(query);
```

The sql generated (from sql server profiler:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[QbTxnItemId] AS [QbTxnItemId], 
[Extent1].[ListType] AS [ListType], 
[Extent1].[QbTxnId] AS [QbTxnId], 
[Extent1].[QbEditSequence] AS [QbEditSequence], 
[Extent1].[TxnNumber] AS [TxnNumber], 
[Extent1].[RefNumber] AS [RefNumber], 
[Extent1].[TxnDate] AS [TxnDate], 
[Extent1].[TxnAmt] AS [TxnAmt], 
[Extent1].[IsPaid] AS [IsPaid], 
[Extent1].[IsCleared] AS [IsCleared], 
[Extent1].[LastGetAll] AS [LastGetAll], 
[Extent1].[GetIsCleared] AS [GetIsCleared], 
[Extent1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
[Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
[Extent1].[RecordStatus] AS [RecordStatus], 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent1].[TableID] AS [TableID]
FROM [dbo].[QbTxnItems] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (N'Invoice' = [Extent1].[ListType]) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
1 AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Payments] AS [Extent2]
WHERE ([Extent2].[QbTxnId] = [Extent1].[QbTxnId]) AND ([Extent2].[QbTxnId] IS NOT NULL)
)) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
1 AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[QbTxnIgnores] AS [Extent3]
WHERE [Extent3].[QbTxnId] = [Extent1].[QbTxnId]
))
ORDER BY [Extent1].[RefNumber] ASC
```

will not complete in any reasonable amount of time when executed from Entity Framework, but executes instantaneously from SSMS.

Using take(200) to limit the number of rows to 200, the query runs in about 50 msecs even when called from EF.  Increasing the number of rows to 500 increases the time to over 5 seconds.

This seems to be inappropriate performance.  EF must be capable of returning more than a few hundred rows in a reasonable amount of time.  Are there any settings that can be adjusted to increase the capability for running larger queries from EF?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but I'd switch your p.QbTxnId != null check to be the first in that Any() statement to short circuit the comparison. That would probably speed this up just a little bit.

Comment: First, 7200 is a lot of rows, you might want to look at narrowing that down a bit if you can, or look at paging your data. Second, are there any large datatypes (huge strings, file contents, etc)?

Comment: Does SSMS return the complete result set quickly, or does it only begin streaming the results to the Results pane quickly?

Comment: Also, are the connections in EF and SSMS identical? I mean, ANSI settings, coallation, etc. Are there any ambient transactions in the EF code that are not present in SSMS?

Comment: I have already added paging to my code, however it seems to me that something that takes essentially no time to run in SSMS should not take so long to run from ef that I can't even wait for it to finish.  The SSMS result set completes in less than a second.

Comment: Moving the QbTxnId !== check to be first had no effect on the performance!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you could speed this up by actually doing some Joins here.
Try this:

```
    var query = (from i in context.QbTxnItems.AsNoTracking()
                join p in context.Payments on i.QbTxnId equals p.QbTxnId
                join qi in context.QbTxnIgnores on i.QbTxnId equals qi.QbTxnId
                where (i.ListType == "Invoice")
                select i).OrderBy(i => i.RefNumber);
```

Comment: The joins you suggest would be inner joins. I'm actually looking for outer joins where there are no matching records.

Comment: @AlanGodfried, check out [101 Linq Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin) for how to do left outer joins (and others).

Comment: Yes, those joins are inner joins and you would need to modify the code to do left outer joins. See the example that @Gunr2171 posted on how to make these left outer joins.

Comment: Interestingly, after I rewrote the linq as left outer joins and ran the code, the performance was exactly the same as the original code. 500 records took about 5 seconds.

Comment: What did the resulting SQL look like after the joins? and what exactly is going on in RapEntities.GetList(query)?? why not just do query.ToList()?

Comment: RapEntities.GetList(query) is essentially query.ToList() with some standard exception handling built-in.

Comment: The SQL looks like standard left outer join with a where clause specifying null on the right entity.